# what is the solution for php_mysql.dll ext in laravel with php 7 and IIs7

Tags: laravel, iis, php-7

I am using laravel latest framework (5.3.*) with IIS7 and php7. It is showing a warning for create project or any artisan command like

> c:\inetpub\wwwroot\test>php atisan serve PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files\PHP\ v7.0\ext\php_mysql.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application. in Unknown on line 0

I want to create my project with latest version of php and laravel but with php7 the php_mysql.dll is deprecated. How can I prevent the warning of php_mysql.dll?

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy php.ini from a previous installation of PHP 5.x? It looks like you have copied the extensions and php.ini from a previous installation of PHP 5, compiled with a different version of VC or 32/64bit.

To solve the issue, you should just need to open your php.ini, and comment out or remove the line:

extension=php_mysql.dll